# Least squares fit with polynomials: Order of the polynomial vs accuracy of the predictions

Tags: least-squares, gradient-descent, fitting, stochastic-gradient-descent

I have noisy evaluations $y_i$ of some unkown function $f$ at points $\vec{x}_i$ clustered around point $\vec{x^*}$. Now I want to fit a polynomial model to this data to get some surrogate model $\hat{f}$ that I can evaluate to get the function value and gradient at $\vec{x}^*$. Will the order of my polynomial change what $\hat{f}(\vec{x}^*)$ and $\nabla \hat{f}(\vec{x}^*)$ are? Or put more concretely: If I fit a linear model to my data, will I get the same $\hat{f}(\vec{x}^*)$ as when I fit a constant model? And when I fit a quadratic model, will I get the same $\hat{f}(\vec{x}^*)$ as for the linear and constant model and the same $\nabla \hat{f}(\vec{x}^*)$ as for the linear model?

### Linear vs constant case in 1D and 2D

In the linear vs constant model case in 1D the answer is no:

I have $N$ points $x_i$ and values $y_i$ and denote their sample means by
$$
\overline{y} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i y_i \quad ; \quad
\overline{x} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i x_i
$$
and similarly the sample mean of any other quantity.

For the constant model $f(x) = b$, the estimate of $f(x)$ is simply the sample
mean of all samples:
$$
    \hat{f} (\overline{x}) = \overline{y}
$$

For the linear model $f(x) = mx + b$, the [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) $X$ is
$$
    X = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & x_1 \\ ⋮ & ⋮ \\ 1 & x_n
        \end{pmatrix}
    \quad ⇒ ⋯ ⇒ \quad 
    (X^T X)^{-1} = \frac{1}{N(\overline{x^2} - \overline{x}^2)}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \overline{x^2} & -\overline{x} \\ -\overline{x} & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and hence we get the following [estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation):
$$
    \begin{pmatrix} \hat{b} \\ \hat{m} \end{pmatrix}
    = \frac{1}{\overline{x^2} - \overline{x}^2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \overline{x^2}\overline{y} - \overline{x} \, \overline{x y} \\
        \overline{x y} - \overline{x} \, \overline{y} 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
and thus we estimate $f(\overline{x})$ as
$$
    \hat{f}(\overline{x}) = \hat{m} \overline{x} + \hat{b}
    = \frac{
        \overline{x y} \, \overline{x} - \overline{x}^2 \overline{y} 
        + \overline{x^2}\overline{y} - \overline{x} \, \overline{x y}
        }{
        \overline{x^2} - \overline{x}^2
      } = \overline{y},
$$
exactly the same as for the constant model! This implies, that in this case
getting gradient information out of the samples incurs no penalty on the
information about the function value.

The same result with the same strategy can be proven for the 2D case
$f(x_1, x_2) = m_1 x_1 + m_2 x_2 + b$, although of course it takes a good bit more
paper to write down the $3 × 3$ matrix and its inverse.

### Higher dimensions or higher orders

- Is the same statement still true for linear fits and higher-dimensional $\vec{x}$? (I assume yes, but 1D and 2D don't suffice for a proof)
- Is an analogous statement true for the gradient of the function and a quadratic surrogate model $\vec{x}^T Q \vec{x} + \vec{m} \cdot \vec{x} + b$, where $Q$ is a symmetric matrix / quadratic form?

Comment: Could you clarify your basic question, "If I fit a linear model to my data, will I get the same f^(x⃗ ∗) as when I fit a linear model?"  It looks tautological.  The vagueness of your formulation and subsequent discussion make it difficult to deduce what you're trying to ask.

Comment: That was indeed tautological. I meant "If I fit a linear model to my data, will I get the same f^(x) as when I fit a _constant_ model". Fixed that type now.